# No Y wire to thermostat

Tags: thermostat

I am trying to install a Honeywell rth6580wf thermostat. I have located all the wires except Y. It is a gas powered heat and central AC system. At the system there is a Y wire going outside to unit, but not one coming into the house to the thermostat. I have C, G, W, and R(jumpers with Rc). What can I do to get the Y wires to the thermostat?[image]

Comment: Does the current thermostat control cooling?  Unless it's a smart thermostat, it doesn't need a C (common) wire, so it could be using that to control cooling.  You need to trace the red and white wires connected to C and Y in your picture and see where they lead.

Comment: Yes it controls cooling as well. The red and white C and Y wires  go outside to the ac unit. In the current thermostat there wasn’t a wire connected to the Y terminal. Would it be possible to connect the G and Y on the system and then just connect the G on the smart thermostat to control the fan and AC?

Comment: Clearly there is a Y wire as it's in the photo.  Might it be clipped off at the thermostat end?